# Set "Important"-message red, other white

Tags: c#, console-application, textcolor

I'm building a calendar and I want to set the important meetings red, the others white. How can I achieve that? When I set the color for the last row red the not important meetings are also red. My code:

```
string important;
Console.Write("High priority? input yes or no: ");
important = Console.ReadLine();

if (important == "yes" || important == "Yes")
{
    important = "Important";
}
else
{
    important = "Normal";
}

Console.Write("Priority: " + important);
```

Comment: to deal with such 'yes' or 'YES', just reformat the string to contain only capital or only lower letters and compare it then

Comment: @mikus: instead of *reformating the string* just compare it as `String.Equals("yes", important, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: well, youre right, in c# its a better option, I thought about general rule :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `ForeGroundColor` to `Red`, you have to reset it to `Gray` which is the default color. You can use this code

```
Console.Write("High priority? input yes or no: ");
string important = Console.ReadLine();

if (important.Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.Write("Priority: ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; 
    Console.Write("Important");        
}
else
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("Priority: Normal");
}
Console.ResetColor(); //default
```

Comment: Check my answer. It's almost the same but mine works without `important.Equals`. Why do I need this there?

Comment: @user5462581 main difference is *resetting the color*. `important.Equals` with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` will take care of "yes" in any case like  - YES, yes, yEs etc.

Comment: Nice to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Console.ForegroundColor`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color) Like this:

```
important = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Priority: ");

if (important == "yes" || important == "Yes")
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red ;
    important = "Important";
}
else
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    important = "Normal";
}
Console.Write(important);
```

Comment: When I am doing it like this the message "Priority: [...]" in the last row also gets red. I only want the output "important" red and the output "normal" in white. That is the clue.

Comment: @user5462581, so set color before output what you needed - if you output `"Priority: [...]"` logicaly all this string apply selected color

Comment: The problem is that I don't only have this for output. Also something like meeting members, meeting title etc. and they're all red if I do it like this.

Comment: @user5462581...as *Grundy* said : *set color before output what you needed*. This is just an example for this requirement you can change it as your need.

Comment: @user5462581 when you set color for console, it applied for output after, so if you set `Red` output _inportant_ and then try output somthing else - you still output in `Red`.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Arghya C's answer.**

Old code:

```
string important;

      Console.Write("\n\nIs the meeting high priority?\n Input \"Yes\" or \"No\": ");

      important = Console.ReadLine();

if (important == "yes" || important == "Yes")
      {
        Console.Write("\nPriority: \t");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("Important");
      }
      else
      {
        Console.Write("\nPriority: \t");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write("Normal");
      }
```

Comment: I really don't see any important difference between your solution and my answer!

Comment: Do you see it now? I don't change the variables value. I write "Important" with `Console.Write`. You change the string value and output the value itself.

Comment: Well why it should be matter either change the color of the variable or yours? you are repeating `Console.Write` twice in `if` and in `else` statement. it's not a good idea.

Comment: But for my case it didn't work in another way. I **only** want the message "important" red. Nothing else.

Comment: Well I think you didn't test my answer after I updated it. in my updated answer only  the message "important" would be `Red`!

Comment: I did test it. But my program is a bit bigger than just this and it won't cooperate with each other. But thanks for your help!